# Cassandra - Datamodel

Tags: cassandra, data-modeling, bigdata, cql3

i'm new to Cassandra and i'm not certain how to model my data.

Lets assume the object i want to store look like this:
C_ID,
VALUE,
TIMESTAMP,
D_TYPE,
E_ID

Currently i'm storing the data in a RDBMS with C_ID and Timestamp as Primary Key.
I'm aware that i should model my data around the selects/deletes i have to do in NoSQL.

The Select i want to would always have an C_ID, but can additionaly contain timestamp, d_type and E_id
SO manditory: C_ID
and maybe: timestamp, d_type, e_id

The delete i want to go through time.
Delete from columnfamliy where time < Date;

And here comes the problem. As far as i've researched: The primary key from a cf has to be in the select and in the delete.
So in my case that would make timestamp the only possible primary key since i have it in select + delete.
And that a big problem since i have get data from multiple maschines and i cant garrentie that a time (even to the ms, will only happen one) and another problem is that i cant really query over range anymore.
And i can only delete with IN or = syntax, and if i have to delete for example 1 day i'm looking at a batch statement with 86400000 delete (with ms).

So atm i'm totally stuck with the problem =/
Anyone knows anything helpful?

Thanks in advance.

**-- UPDATE 1**
I'm using C# and the datastax driver atm.

Comment: With your deletes are they on a regular interval such that you could use a TTL instead of having to perform a DELETE FROM?

Comment: I thought about using TTL, and i think its the only way around the big mess =/ Just wanted to see if someone know another solution than TTL. I think i could also use a small cf with TTL for all the hot data (last 90 days) and one big table for longtime save for all. There has to be a another way around this with a better data model =/

Comment: Is there a relationship between c_id and time?